# How to get the URL of an Instagram post from the media_share_url?

Tags: json, url, instagram

When requesting to download your Instagram profile data, you get your conversations in a JSON file. A shared post in a conversation translates to the following in the JSON file:

```
{
  "sender": "username",
  "created_at": "2021-02-29T05:34:34.866155+00:00",
  "media_owner": "bloombergbusiness",
  "media_share_caption": "The world is finally losing its taste for meat. Last year was only the second since 1961 in which meat production fell and it’s headed for another decline this year.\n\nBeef is clearly declining as a percentage of total meat production—that’s huge for the climate. Emissions from its production are about 10 times higher than from either pork or chicken. \n\nNow investors are betting more than $1 billion on alternative proteins this year. Click the link in our bio to read more.",
  "media_share_url": "https://scontent-atl3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/116427336_158250425871714_8283380464202749985_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=InoAagAFZN4AX_f89en&oh=4337b2808755d718c329088688ba9fcd&oe=5F5AF234&ig_cache_key=MjM2NTE4MTQ2Mzk1OTE2MDM1MQ%3D%3D.2"
}
```

The URL ìn `media_share_url` is ephemeral, so after some time it will expire, simply returning "URL signature expired".

My question is:

Is there any way of getting the original URL from that `media_share_url`? In the above example that would be https://www.instagram.com/p/CDS0AKcn8Yf. Alternatively, getting the [thumbnail url](https://instagram.fmad8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/116427336_158250425871714_8283380464202749985_n.jpg?tp=1&_nc_ht=instagram.fmad8-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=nnAmCi9HkHgAX8eQT-Z&ccb=7-4&oh=c0fb51e3d6bdefdf05896a14f97a9421&oe=607F9F34&_nc_sid=83d603) would also be fine.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

If you have this information, you can use it.

1. Media ID
2. Post ID

You can try using them..

Java Code:

```
   public static String getInstagramPostId(String mediaId) {
    String postId = "";
    try {
        long id = Long.parseLong(mediaId.substring(0, mediaId.indexOf('_')));
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

        while (id > 0) {
            long remainder = (id % 64);
            id = (id - remainder) / 64;
            postId = alphabet.charAt((int)remainder) + postId;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return postId;
 }
```

You can check this link for javascript

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please provide a working example with the `media_share_url` that is in the question? Also, for clarification, as stated in the question, I don't have de media ID, but the `media_share_url`, they are different.